# What are good ways to express the action of "studying a textbook"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-request

I want to say something like

> I am **working through** the textbook  A.

By which I mean, reading the book (and occasionally rereading certain paragraphs), doing (almost) all of its exercises and thinking about the topics that are taught in that textbook. Essentially using that textbook for self-studying.

I am not sure if that expression "working through" is right or if it sounds somewhat natural to an English speaker.

What are some good expressions to use for the situation I described above?

Comment: *I am* ***working my way through*** . . .

Comment: "..working through the textbook", is perfectly acceptable English usage.

Comment: Can you perhaps think of some alternatives then?

Comment: As @James says, *I'm working through the textbook* is perfectly acceptable. But if you're going to specifically identify it as ***textbook A***, you shouldn't precede it by the article ***the***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Even if A is replaced by the title of the textbook?

Comment: Definitely! Suppose your textbook is called *English for Beginners*. You wouldn't say *I'm working through the English for Beginners.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers But I would say "I am working through the textbook 'English for Beginners' ", right?

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure what the technical term is for your last example, but it's the same as, for example, *What do we know about this man Smith?*, where ***this*** is another determiner (which could be replaced by ***the, that, her***, etc.). The construction applies when you use two *consecutive* noun phrases that both refer to the same thing. In all these examples we could (and often *would*) insert *[which/who is] **called*** between those two NPs. We don't usually *need* to do this, but it would be almost unavoidable in, say, *Do you know a man **called** Smith?*

Comment: Agreed. I had assumed that the A at the end was just a typo and the sentence was supposed to end with "textbook".

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with

> I'm working through the textbook *English for Beginners*.

You could use

> I'm working my way through the textbook.
>   I'm using *English for Beginners* to study.
>   I'm studying English using *English for Beginners*